# pandas.Series.to_csv or pandas.Series.to_excel - How to export two serie into on csv or xlsx file?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I have those series :

```
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
ser = pd.Series(data=d, index=['a', 'b', 'c']).rename('ser')

d2 = {'adf': 3, 'dfg': 6}
ser2 = pd.Series(data=d2, index=['adf', 'dfg']).rename('ser2')
```

I can export them individually as csv with :

```
ser.to_csv('ser.csv',sep=';')
ser2.to_csv('ser2.csv',sep=';')
```

I would like to export them into one common csv file :

[image]

How should I proceed ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I advise against including the series name halfway down your csv file, as it will make parsing the csv much more difficult, you can achieve this by using the `mode` parameter in pandas' `to_csv` method:

```
ser.rename('ser').to_csv('series.csv', sep=';')
ser2.rename('ser2').to_csv('series.csv', sep=';', mode='a')
```

This will result in a csv containing:

```
;ser
a;1
b;2
c;3
;ser2
adf;3
dfg;6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the shell command `cat ser2.csv >> ser.csv`, or in Python:

```
with open('ser_combined.csv', 'w') as f:
    for fname in ['ser.csv', 'ser2.csv']:
        with open(fname) as in_f:
            f.write(in_f.read())
```